# "Вы сама" или "вы сами"?

Tags: согласование

Предложение такое: "Вы можете сама (сами) себе улучшить судьбу". Как правильнее написать: "вы сами" или "вы сама"?
Спасибо

Comment: Вопрос отличный, но ответ неоднозначный)

Comment: Может быть все-таки Вы Сами?..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я склоняюсь к ответу "вы сами", ведь не скажешь: "Девушка, ну что вы натворила!" Правильно сказать: "Девушка, ну что вы натворили!"

Answer (score 1):

Если речь идет о собеседнице (не собеседницах!), то надо употребить местоимение "сама"

Comment: В книжках не искала, но не представляю, чтобы  я сказала директору: Вы сама знаете! Для меня это то же самое, что обратиться на "ты". Т.е. "ты сама", но "Вы сами" - независимо от того, к одной женщине обращаюсь или к нескольким.

Comment: Бог с нею, с директором, говорите ей: "Вы сами знаете", пока она однажды не скажет Вам: "Вы знаете, я случайно прочитала на каком-то форуме по русскому языку, так там один из умников настаивает на том, что правильнее надо говорить: "Вы сама знаете". А как Вы сама считаете?" (это ОНА к Вам обращается, а не Я к Вам - потому что Вы для меня, как директор для Вас: как-то боязно сказать Вам: "Вы сама")"

Answer (score 1):

"Вы сама", "Вы одна", "Вы первый", "Вы та, которая обещала мне всё, но не дала ничего" и т. д. - подобные фразы, думаю (уверен, убеждён!), надо писать в форме единственного числа, а все глаголы - во множественном числе. Да, это не соответствует, не согласуется с общим правилом, да, это одна из, очередная трудность русского языка, но я полностью согласен с виктор1799. Если Грамота.ру противоречит интуиции, за которой стоит правильное написание, значит, Грамота.ру надо исправлять в соответствии с интуицией, поставить её в соответствие с интуицией... Категоричность, как вы понимаете, шуточная.

Answer (score 0):

Грамота.ру считает, что правильно "вы сами". Там этот вопрос и на форуме обсуждался, но официальный источник, подтверждающий или опровергающий эту позицию, найти не удалось.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, возможны оба варианта.
Все зависит от взаимоотношений собеседников, как ни странно это может прозвучать в контексте грамматического спора.
Если говорящий безусловно уважает свою собеседницу или разница в положении значительна, то "вы сами", без всяких исключений. Если же обращение на вы чисто формально (просто элементарная гражданская вежливость, без учтивости), или старые приятели по жизни, родственники, но интеллигентное общение на вы... тогда конструкция "вы сама" явно предпочтительнее.
*Вы сами мне приказали, Софья Андреевна!*
*Вы сама должны Митеньку уговорить, Танюша, ему же скоро должны вызов прислать...*
В подтверждение второго, *фамильярного* варианта, приведу примеры из Нацкорпуса :

> М. И. Цветаева. Пленный дух (Моя встреча с Андреем Белым) (1934)
> И вдруг, со всей безудержностью настоящего откровения: ― **Да вы сама, Ася, барс!** Это вы с себя шкуру сняли: надели.
>
> Ф. К. Сологуб. Мелкий бес (1902)
> Вам не надо богатого мужа, ― говорил Передонов, ― **вы сама богатая**.