# Вы сам / Вы сами

Tags: грамматика

Если обращаюсь к одному человеку?
Вы сам/сами это можете. Вы сам/сами себе противоречите.

Все время об это спотыкаюсь, а четкого правила не видел. Я тяготею к первому варианту - единственного числа. Ссылки на общую грамматику здесь не проходят, вежливая форма - это не множественное число, это именно вежливая форма, которая не обязана всюду следовать грамматике множественного.

Сравните с английскими yourself и yourselves.

Вот и пример нашелся...
"Вы сами дурак" или "Вы сам дурак"?

Comment: Есть похожий вопрос, по которому консенсус не был достигнут: http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/32746/%D0%92%D1%8B-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8

Comment: да, спасибо. Странно, что я его пропустил. Ну теперь уже поздно переносить туда. Если только модераторы помогут.

Answer (score 4):

Правил согласования никто не отменял. По причине вежливости Вы употребили форму подлежащего во множ. числе или нет, но подлежащее будет согласовываться с определением и сказуемым тоже во множ. числе. В литературном языке, конечно, а в устной речи, по-моему, возможно и "Вы сам", "Вы сама", если отношения полуофициальные. Часто в именительном говорят "Вы сами", в остальных падежах в ед. числе: вас самого/самой, с вами самим/самой, вам самому/самой.

Вот в энциклопедии "Кругосвет", например:

Однако для вежливого вы (относящегося к одному лицу) имеются исключения: в предложениях с подлежащим вы и составным сказуемым, именная часть которого выражена полной формой прилагательного или существительным, эта именная часть должна быть в форме единственного числа: Я знаю, что вы студент; Сразу видно, что вы умная. Если же именная часть выражена кратким прилагательным или при вы стоит местоимение сами, то используются формы множественного числа: Вы умны, хороши собой; Вы сами это придумали? (неправильно: *Вы умна, хороша собой; Вы сам (сама) это придумали?*). Если при местоимении вы есть слово один в значении "только", то согласования вы и слова один по числу не происходит, а сказуемое согласуется с подлежащим вы по множественному числу: Вы один пришли? (не: *Вы один пришел?* и не: *Вы одни пришли?* – последний вопрос может быть понят только как обращение к нескольким лицам).

http://www.krugosvet.ru/enc/lingvistika/mestoimeniya

Comment: Да, спасибо. Но мне как-то не нравятся полуразмытые формулировки типа "в разговорном возможно". Я подумаю. Радует, что все-таки какие-то оговорки по грамматике числа есть. Значит, не все так безнадежно.

Answer (score 0):

> > Вот и пример нашелся... "Вы сами дурак" или "Вы сам дурак"?

"Сами Вы дурак!" — на мой взгляд, самое лучшее. Или уж "Вы сами дурак".

@Людмила:

> > ...в устной речи, по-моему, возможно и "Вы сам", "Вы сама", если отношения полуофициальные.

Вот уж никогда бы не согласился.